How to debug Android app running on phone when phone is not connected by USB
I am writing an app using IONIC/Angular. My IDE is Visual Studio running on a WIN 11 desktop.  The app that I am writing is an automobile app that is communicating with an OBD-II device plugged into a car.  In order to test the app I have to take the phone to the car and run the app.  If there are problems, I have no way to see the console output or any other debugging outputs.  I feel sure that there must be a way to debug apps that are run remotely like this. Does anyone have any suggestions?
When I run the app in the car and it stops operating unexpectedly, I have no idea why without being able to look at console output or any other debugging information.
Now it is a non-question.  I figured out how to implement WiFi debugging through ADB with the help of this link:
https://www.xamarinexpert.it/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-and-say-goodbye-to-cables/
I was able to connect my phone wirelessly to VS Code and download my app, through the following command in the terminal:
"ionic cap run android --livereload --external"
Then I could access the output from the app through the Chrome browser and "chrome://inspect/devices"
The device and app appear in the browser window, click on "inspect" and there is all the console and debugging information.  I have already solved a few problems that were driving me nuts!

Just Google the terms Android WiFi debugging.

The Android Debug Bridge (ADB) works over USB or Wifi
Connect to Device Over Wifi
